# Using a custom formula on a sheet that is constantly expanding

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

A custom formula for 5 possible colors, by day is used to highlight entries by DayOfWeek

Is it possible to use a format like A2:A instead of manually editing it as the sheet grows bigger?

Formula works fine, just don't want to be editing it continuously

Example for rows A2 to A641 - can this be $A$2:$A ?

```
=and(isblank($A$2:$A$641)=false,OR(weekday($A$2:$A$641)=7))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can NOT use open ranges in Conditional Formatting.

Still.

**Select a range till last row** as a range **and the range will auto expand** to new rows as the sheet expands.

*(In your case `A2:A641` will become `A2:A741` when a 100 rows added)*

EDIT
(following OP's shared sheet)

You also need to change your formulas and use open ranges within them.
As an example:

```
=and(isblank(A2:A)=false,weekday(A2:A)=1)
```

*(Please check your sheet)*

[image]

Comment: How is that inserted into the color rules ? There is no such selection option

Comment: Can you please share a test sheet?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QwLFdBW9zZlRAup3rGjl0c5Ql0stN-fVubPzbImayzg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you